# The bowling game kata in pythonic python

Tags: python

I made an attempt to solve Uncle Bobs bowling game kata (http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata) but didn't really find a solution that felt pythonic enough.

This solution is more or less an adaptation of Martins C++ solution and uses array indexes to calculate scores for strikes and spares. It works but doesn't feel quite as pythonic as I would like it to be.

```
class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        self.rolls = []

    def roll(self, pins):
        self.rolls.append(pins)

    def score_c(self):
        total_score = 0
        frame_index = 0
        for frame in range(10):
            if self.rolls[frame_index] == 10:
                 total_score += 10 + self.rolls[frame_index + 1] + self.rolls[frame_index + 2]
                frame_index +=1
            elif self.rolls[frame_index] + self.rolls[frame_index + 1] == 10:
                total_score += 10 + self.rolls[frame_index + 1]
                frame_index += 2
            else:
                total_score += self.rolls[frame_index] + self.rolls[frame_index + 1]
                frame_index += 2
        return total_score
```

I could have used convenience functions for strike and spare conditions, but you get the picture.

But I thought there must be a way to do it without accessing the rolls array directly though indexes. That feels like a very c-like way of doing it and incrementing frame_index directly definitely doesn't feel right in python. So I think there must be a neater way to do it. I made an attempt below which didn't really work for perfect games.

This one use a generator to provide frames which felt pretty neat but it also meant that 0 had to be added for strikes to make complete 2 roll frames.

```
class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        self.rolls = []

    def _frame_iterator(self):
        for i in range(0, 20, 2):
            yield (self.rolls[i], self.rolls[i+1])

    def roll(self, pins):
        self.rolls.append(pins)
        if pins == 10:
            self.rolls.append(0)

    def score(self):
        total_score = 0
        spare = False
        strike = False
        for frame in self._frame_iterator():
            if spare:
                total_score += frame[0]
                spare = False
            if strike:
                total_score += frame[1]
                strike = False
            if frame[0] + frame[1] == 10:
                spare = True
            if frame[0] == 10:
                strike = True
            total_score += frame[0] + frame[1]
        return total_score
```

My questions are basically, has anyone solved the bowling kata in Python in a different and more pythonic way than uncle bobs C++ solution? And suggestions how to improve on my attempt?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a different approach (implementing most of the rules in `roll()`, instead of `score()`), and I think it's pretty pythonic too.

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._score = [[]]

    def roll(self, pins):
        # start new frame if needed
        if len(self._score[-1]) > 1 or 10 in self._score[-1]:
            self._score.append([])

        # add bonus points to the previous frames
        for frame in self._score[-3:-1]:
            if sum(frame[:2]) >= 10 and len(frame) < 3:
                frame.append(pins)

        # add normal points to current frame
        for frame in self._score[-1:10]:
            frame.append(pins)

    def score(self):
        return sum(sum(x) for x in self._score)
```

The main idea here is instead of storing all rolls in a single list, to make a list of frames that contains a list of rolls (and bonus points) for each frame.

What makes it pythonic is for example the generator expression in the score method.

Another pythonic example is the use of list slices. A previous version of middle part of `roll()` I did looked like:

```
for i in [2, 3]:
    if len(self._score) >= i:
        sum(self._score[-i][:2]) >= 10 and len(self._score[-i]) < 3:
            self._score[-i].append(pins)
```

The elegant thing of the current version using a list slice is that you don't have to check whether the list is long enough to look 1 or 2 frames back. Moreover, you get a nice local variable (`frame = self._score[-i]`) for free, without having to dedicate a separate line for it.